# Spring AOP within pointcut

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, aspectj, spring-aop

```
package com.vanilla.daoService;

    @Repository("daoService")
    public class DaoServiceImpl implements DaoService {

        @Override
        public String addStudent(Student student) {
            //saving new user
             }

        @Override
        public String updateStudent(Student student) {
            //update new user
             }

        @Override
        public String getStudent(String id) {
            //update new user
             }
    }
```

my Business Logic class:

```
package com.vanilla.blService;

@Service("blService") 
public class BlServiceImpl implements BlService {

    @Autowired
    DaoService daoService;

@Override
public void updateStudent(String id){
   Student s = daoService.getStudent(id);
   set.setAddress(address);
   daoService.updateStudent(s);
}

}
```

Now I would like to measure execution of all methods executed within each of Business logic functions (daoservice.*)

I create my Aspect classes

```
@Aspect
public class BlServiceProfiler {

    @Pointcut("within(com.vanilla.blService.BlService.*)")
    public void businessLogicMethods(){}

      @Around("businessLogicMethods()")
      public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
          long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
          System.out.println("Going to call the method " + pjp.toShortString());
          Object output = pjp.proceed();
          System.out.println("Method execution completed.");
          long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
          System.out.println(pjp.toShortString()+" execution time: " + elapsedTime + " milliseconds.");
          return output;
      }

}
```

Unfortunately, nothing happened. I think my `@PointCut` definition is incorrect how can I do it correctly?

Comment: Did you register the aspect with Spring? (Just checking...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
@Pointcut("within(com.vanilla.blService.BlService+)")
public void businessLogicMethods(){}
```

`BlService+` means BlService and all subclasses / implementing classes.

Comment: I tested it and it looks like it applied on BlService.updateStudent instead of daoService methods, because it's printing Going to call the method execution(BlService.updateStudent(..))

Comment: If you want it to apply to the DAOs instead then change it to `within(com.vanilla.daoService.DaoService+)`. Your question says you want to pointcut DAOs but your code sample implies you're trying pointcut services, its a bit confusing.

Comment: @Niall, so what is the difference between @Pointcut("within(com.vanilla.blService.BlService+)"), @Pointcut("within(com.vanilla.blService.BlService.*)") and @Pointcut("execute(* com.vanilla.blService.BlService.*(..))") all of them have the same result?

Comment: In this case they will produce the same result because there just so happens so be an overlap ie. Your services are all in the same package AND all extend BIService. I was just pointing out that your original questions says you wish to pointcut everything in the package daoservice, but your pointcuts all reference the package blservice.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the below pointcut

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.vanilla.blService.BlService.*(..))")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
within(com.vanilla.blService.BlService) && execution(public * com.vanilla.daoService..*.*(..))
```

Comment: I'm getting : nested exception is org.aspectj.weaver.tools.UnsupportedPointcutPrimitiveException: Pointcut expression 'businessLogicMethods()' contains unsupported pointcut primitive 'call'

Comment: Excuse me. I've forgotten `call` isn't supported in @AspectJ in Spring. Try to use `execution` as in fixed code.

Comment: Unfortunately, i t's not executed, looks like it missing pointCut.